# I need help choosing my type of internet connection

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, network-configuration, proxy

I just downloaded the Tor Browser. When first launching, how do I know which network setting to select?

[image]

"I would like to connect directly to Tor network" or "This computer's Internet connection is censored,filtered, or proxied" are the two options. What does the second option mean?

Answer (score 2):

First try "connect directly to Tor network". Normally it works. If it doesn't work then check whether you are using any proxy to connect to internet or not. Bridges are required when your ISP stops connecting to Tor network.